# Android to PC communication

Tags: android

I am working on a project to guide blind students. I am using WiFi Tags and android mobile.
WiFi tags are placed on the wall and android is carried by blind student. The student's time table, shortest path algorithm to reach specific lecture hall is loaded onto HOST.

Whenever android mobiles comes in vicinity of any Wifi tag, it receives the beacons from WiFi Tag. In order to achieve this, android has to scan all the wifi devices every 3 sec(say).So, the android has to forward the WiFi tag id (mac address), android mac id, Received Signal Strength to the HOST. So, how should I do this? What are the different applications to be loaded onto the android mobile?  How should the scanning be done?

Once HOST receives the data from android, it will determine the shortest path in accordance to algorithm and has to send back instruction (say direction - Go Left) to android. So, how can we do this? Since the student is visually impaired, the incoming msg should be audio.

Please let me know how to achieve this? I am new to android.

Thanks
Shaban

Comment: would it be the WiFi tags be replaced by NFC tags? Embed the information into the NFC tags and read from them. Of course, your Android has to be NFC chip.

Comment: Then the user will have to know where the NFC tags are and get reasonably close to them for a tag to be detected. This is not practical with blind students. I think WiFi tags would be ideal. I suggest you research on how Google's indoor maps work. AFAIK they use a low frequency GPS like signal than can be detected from a distance. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Nice Idea ! Stick with Wifi tags, as NFC wont be a ideal solution !

Have you thought of the problems?Each school will have a different arcitecture, how do you plan to counter that?

As far as audio signals are concerned, u could use TTS(Text To Speech) converter to convert the recieved text into audio.!

Coming to wifi tags part, you could use something like this:
A student runs the app and the app in turn sends a particular msg/request thus making the wifi tags recognise that a student needs directions, then u could go on to improve it by student telling the phone where/which class to go to and the wifi tags/server calculates the path and then u could guide the student by using Navigation! Have a look at the documentation for Navigation app from google !

Also if you need my help let me know :)